# Как использовать метод редюс на полную?

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить массив всех умений всех пользователей (поле skills), при этом не должно быть повторяющихся умений и они должны быть отсортированы в алфавитном порядке. Я решила задачу таким способом

```js
'use strict';
var users = [{
    id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
    name: 'Moore Hensley',
    email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 37,
  },
  {
    id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
    name: 'Sharlene Bush',
    email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 34,
  },
  {
    id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
    name: 'Ross Vazquez',
    email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
    name: 'Elma Head',
    email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 21,
  },
  {
    id: '334f8cb3-eb04-45e6-abf4-4935dd439b70',
    name: 'Carey Barr',
    email: 'careybarr@nurali.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Jordan Sampson', 'Eddie Strong'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    skills: ['ex', 'culpa', 'nostrud'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 27,
  },
  {
    guid: '150b00fb-dd82-427d-9faf-2879ea87c695',
    name: 'Blackburn Dotson',
    email: 'blackburndotson@furnigeer.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Jacklyn Lucas', 'Linda Chapman'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    skills: ['non', 'amet', 'ipsum'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 38,
  },
  {
    id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
    name: 'Sheree Anthony',
    email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 39,
  },
];
const getSortedUniqueSkills = users => {
  return users
    .reduce((allSkills, user) => {
      allSkills.push(...user.skills);
      return allSkills;
    }, [])
    .filter((user, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(user) === index)
    .sort();
};
console.log(getSortedUniqueSkills(users));
```

Но мне сделали замечание что редюс работает не на полную , не могу понять каким еще способом можно решить эту задачу. Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: как минимум filter можно убрать и делать проверку в reduce, как максимум - сорт тоже можно убрать

Comment: убрала сорт все работает. Но не могу понять как сделать проверку именно в reduce

Comment: не, если просто сорт убрать, то в зависимости от входных данных итоговый массив может быть как отсортированным так и нет. Проверка напрямую переносится в reduce, вместо безусловного добавления элементов нужно просто каждый элемент проверять перед добавлением

Answer (score 0):

Что имел в виду ваш преподаватель надо узнавать у него/неё, но как правило уникальные коллекции реализуются с помощью класса [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) ([множество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85))):

```js
const users = Object.freeze([{
  skills: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
}, {
  skills: ['c', 'b', 'd'],
}, {
  skills: ['d', 'c', 'e'],
}]);

const skills = Object.freeze(users.reduce((allSkills, user) => {
  user.skills.forEach(s => allSkills.add(s));
  return allSkills;
}, new Set()));

console.log(Array.from(skills).sort());
// > Array ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```